# A way to get image from A Tweet

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am trying to extract image(media_url) from a tweet.
The problem is: the only thing I have is the tweet which I get(from the share intent) when you want to share a tweet in Android Application.
I don't see an API in which we invoke tweet and that returns us the image URL.
Is there a way to fetch the image url from the tweet shared via Share button from Twitter Application?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {    
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
            Log.v("SAURAV"," Size is ::" + keys.size()); 
            for (String string : keys) {
                String image_url = intent.getStringExtra(string);
                Log.v("SAURAV","image_url ::"+image_url);
            }

            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {        
                String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+sharedText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*Log.d("Saurav","URL We get :"+image_url);*/
                Log.d("Saurav","SharedText is:"+sharedText);
                handleShare(intent);

            } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
        }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code of what have you tried do far?

Comment: @pablisco Find my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunally Twitter doesn't give you that information. I've tested with one of my tweets and the only data that you get is this for extras:

```
KEY: android.intent.extra.SUBJECT
VALUE: "Tweet from Pablisco (@pablisc0)"
KEY: android.intent.extra.TEXT
VALUE: "Pablisco (@pablisc0) tweeted at 11:26 am on Fri, Apr 13, 2012: @metrerovolador guay, por Brighton este finde. Aprovechando el comienzo de la primavera :) http://t.co/ZU2ZzmD8 (https://twitter.com/pablisc0/status/190747704115204096?s=09) Get the official Twitter app at https://twitter.com/download?s=13"
KEY: tweet_id
VALUE: 190747704115204096
```

You can use the twitter API to fetch the data from twitter itself (using the `tweet_id` property) To get more info on how to use the Twitter API follow this link: https://dev.twitter.com

(outside of the scope of the question to show how to use the Twitter API)

Comment: I ll try getting it via ID and return back. Will post the code details.

Comment: Hey @pablisco while extracting data from intent I'm getting only "android.intent.extra.TEXT". I'm not able to fetch the tweet_id. I'm using the following code to fetch the key's from the bundle

Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
Log.v("SAURAV"," Size is ::" + keys.size()); 

But everytime I get the size as 1 and when I print the contains I get the tweet text only. Are you sure we get ID also ?

Comment: Is it from the Twitter App or the website? **Edit:** Ok I just reread your question and it's from the app. I'm not sure since it's in the data that I get from the Twitter app

Comment: Not a problem @pablisco but I thought you were getting those values as bundles. I am almost sure now the android app's share intent only gives TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

Finally could achieve this with little bit of backdoor method:
The text intent which we received from the app has a media_id embedded in the link.

1. 1)Extract that id from the text.
2. 2)Invoke this api:
   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=
3. 3)The response will be JSON. Then traverse to "extended_entities"
   and inside this "media" array and on traversing this you'll find
   "media_url" which will be the actual image link.